# Is it possible to limit the numbers of observations per page for proc report

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am just wondering if there are any options can be used to limit the number of observations printed per page in Proc Report procedure?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends in part on the destination.

`PROC REPORT` in page-sensitive destinations, like `ODS LISTING` or `ODS PDF`, can be convinced to limit observations a few ways.

`ODS LISTING`: `OPTIONS PS=[#]` will set the page size.  `PS` option on `PROC REPORT` statement also does this.  See [PROC REPORT statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/69850/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dz7jdasx5t56n1rmlx346dyk6n.htm) for more.

`ODS PDF`, `ODS RTF`, other page-sensitive destinations: Create a page variable that stores which page an observation falls on.

```
ods pdf;

data cars;
  set sashelp.cars;
  if mod(_n_,20)=0 then page_num+1;
run;

proc report data=cars;
  columns make model page_num;
  define page_num/ order noprint;
  break after page_num/page;
run;
ods pdf close;
```